# How can I tell react-native what .env file to look at?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, environment-variables, environment

On windows, I'm developing a white label app and trying to use env variables to make code specific builds. I'm using `react-native-config` and I followed their setup on GitHub, but for some reason `SET ENVFILE=.env.myenvironment` doesn't do anything for me, even with a defined map in `build-gradle` like this:

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
debug: ".env",
release: ".env",
anothercustombuild: ".env.custombuild",
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using vscode integrated terminal to pass the `react-native-config` command to tell RN which .env file to look at, and it wasnt working at all..

I started using powershell for windows and tryed the correct command for it. And it work wonders. e.g.
`$env:ENVFILE=".env.mycustomenvironment"; react-native run-android`. It should work the same for `react-native run-ios` as well as for release builds.

Keep in mind that as of right now (08/20/2019), `react-native-config` isnt working properly with product flavors in RN 0.60+ when it comes to exposing the .env vars to your .JS files, if you are looking for a workaround for that, take a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395763/how-do-i-write-flavor-specifc-code-in-react-native) but tl;dr is to use `react-native-config` with `react-native-build-config`.

Comment: Many thanks @LuizfBrisighello, This solution saved my day. I have been struggling from past 2 days to make it work. using 'react-native-build-config' really helped.

Comment: I have fixed this with out using 'react-native-build-config' as well by giving extra effort. You just need to add one line which is mentioned in 'Advanced Android Setup'  of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config 
That is adding 
```defaultConfig {
    ...
    resValue "string", "build_config_package", "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_IN_ANDROIDMANIFEST_XML"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After configuring flavors in your gradle, in order to allow react-native to look at the custom .env files in the root of your project folder you must add to
`android/app/build.gradle`

In my example I am creating two apps for the android device using the same codebase, one for group1 and one for group2

//add this to line 3 of your `app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  projecta: ".env.development.android.projecta",
  projectb: ".env.development.android.projectb",
]
```

//don't forget to add

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  flavorDimensions "default" // add this line
  compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and then match up the keys from this array to your product flavors

```
  productFlavors {
    project1 {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.nativeapp.projecta'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.nativeapp"
    }
    project2 {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        applicationId 'com.nativeapp.projectb'
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.nativeapp"
    }
}
```

also make sure that the applicationId and resValue start with your apps package name

in my case it's 'nativeapp' but you can find yours found in the MainActivity.java file.

you can find this if you dig into android/app/main/java/com/ directory.

After this you can then configure your scripts when needed to look like this

```
"scripts": {
"android:project1": "ENVFILE=.env.development.projecta react-native run-android --variant=projectaDebug --appIdSuffix=projecta",
"android:project2": "ENVFILE=.env.development.projectb.android react-native run-android --variant=projectbDebug --appIdSuffix=projectb",}
```

Note: when adding scripts, the variant must be the flavor name for example 'project2' followed by 'Debug' = 'projectb' as this is your default buildType

Also make sure you've got the relevant folders created in android/app/src/ for each flavour.

in my case

```
android/app/src/projecta/
android/app/src/projecta/
```

if all set up correctly, when you build using the scripts you've created it should create the correct res folder and android manifest files.

If you want to change the name of each individual apps instance, change the strings.xml in the `res/values` directory.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Project1</string> //this will be the name of your app when its built in your emulator
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got react-native-config working with flavors. (RN 0.60+ ) You don't need to use that other library.
heres an example that worked for me for white labeling:

> ```
> project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
>    client1devdebug: ".env.client1.debug",
>    client1devrelease: ".env.client1.release",
>    client2devdebug: ".env.client2.debug",
>    client2devrelease: ".env.client2.release",
> ]
> ```

AND then in configs:

```
 productFlavors {
    client1 {
      dimension "client"
      resValue "string", "build_config_package", "PACKAGE_NAME_IN MANIFEST"
      applicationId "com.app1"
    }
    client2 {
      dimension "client"
      resValue "string", "build_config_package", "PACKAGE_NAME_IN MANIFEST"
      applicationId "com.app2"
    }
      dev {
          ...
          dimension "environment"
      }
      stage {
          minSdkVersion 21
          resValue "string", "app_name", "Stage"
          dimension "environment"
      }
      production {
          minSdkVersion 21
          resValue "string", "app_name", "Prod"
          dimension "environment"
      }
```

Comment: What should the "PACKAGE_NAME_IN MANIFEST" be?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `package.json` file:

```
"yourCustomEnv:android-windows": "SET ENVFILE=.env.yourCustomEnv && npm run android",
"yourCustomEnv:android-mac": "ENVFILE=.env.yourCustomEnv; npm run android",
"yourCustomEnv:ios": "ENVFILE=.env.yourCustomEnv; npm run ios",
```

and then, to run in `yourCustomEnv` mode, run:

**For Android**:

- on windows:

run `npm run yourCustomEnv:android-windows`

- on mac:

run `npm run yourCustomEnv:android-mac`

**For iOS**

run `npm run yourCustomEnv:ios`

**Full example**

if we suppose that your custom environment file is `.env.staging`, add this to your `package.json` file:

```
"staging:android-windows": "SET ENVFILE=.env.staging && npm run android",
"staging:android-mac": "ENVFILE=.env.staging; npm run android",
"staging:ios": "ENVFILE=.env.staging; npm run ios",
```

and then, to run with `.env.staging` variables, run:

**For Android**:

- on windows:

run `npm run staging:android-windows`

- on mac:

run `npm run staging:android-mac`

**For iOS**

run `npm run staging:ios`